# Reducing from 3-COLOR to 3-CNF SAT?

Tags: graphs

I get how to reduce 3-SAT to 3-COLOR, but I'm not sure how to do it the other way around. Does anyone  have any hints or insight?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Did you get stuck somewhere? At least you know that you need propositional variables, and then clauses that use those variables. Given a graph, what do you think you should do first?

Comment: 3-SAT is NP-complete so Cook's theorem gives a reduction once you show that 3-COL is in NP.

Comment: You can use the generic recipe that works for most problems in NP: first express 3-Colouring as a constraint satisfaction problem, then use the direct encoding of the CSP to SAT, and finally add new variables to split any large clauses.  Or you could just let $x_{u,c}$ denote the variable denoting the truth of the proposition "$u$ receives colour $c$", for each $u \in V(G)$ and $c \in \{1,2,3\}$.  Then add clauses to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For each vertex $v$ and color $c$, have a variable $x_{v,c}$ which means "vertex $v$ gets color $c$". Now construct a 3SAT instance that states:

1. Each vertex gets some color.
2. Neighboring vertices get different colors.